# After reading raw response through interceptor, retrofit is not receiving respose in call body

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

If I am adding an interceptor to read the raw response before returning original response via an interceptor I am getting a failure in call of retrofit
my interceptor code:

```
 Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(builder.build());

 String rawJson = originalResponse.body().string();
 try {
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(rawJson);
      if (jsonObject.has("respCode")) {
            if (jsonObject.getString("respCode").equals("E")) {
                context.getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                .putBoolean(AppConstants.IS_LOGGED_IN_KEY, false)
                .apply();
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class));
             }
         }
   } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return originalResponse;
```

There are no compilation errors in it.
without this **try-catch** block everything is working fine.

any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may see example in [HttpLoggingInterceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor/src/main/java/okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor.java#L236)

```
ResponseBody responseBody = originalResponse.body();
BufferedSource source = responseBody.source();
source.request(Long.MAX_VALUE); // Buffer the entire body.
Buffer buffer = source.buffer();
String rawJson = buffer.clone().readString(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```